# MS Access database: Select statement error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying following query in MS Access 2010 database:

**Query:**

```
SELECT     ID, Title, Priority, Workflow_Instance_Step_ID:ID
FROM         Task
```

**Error:**

> Error Source: Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
>   Error Message: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Workflow_Instance_Step_ID:ID'

I know that field "Workflow_Instance_Step_ID:ID" is giving error as it has ':' operator, but I cant change it as it it coming from share point list.

I have tried '[Workflow_Instance_Step_ID:ID]' but still its giving an error.
Please give me your suggestion on the same.

Comment: So what is your data actually stored in? MS Access, SQL Server, or Sharepoint?

Comment: Does it give the same error with the brackets?  It's possible Access thinks "Workflow_Instance_Step_ID" is an Alias.  When you assign an alias to a SELECT statement, access will show it as "Alias: table.field" in the design view.  My best guess is the colon is never allowed in a field name, so regardless of what's coming from Sharepoint, the actual field name likely cannot be Workflow_Instance_Step_ID:ID

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to recreate your issue, at least with a native Access table in Access 2010. I created a table named [baz] with a single text field named [foo:bar]

```
foo:bar
-------
this   
is     
a      
test
```

and the query

```
SELECT [foo:bar] FROM baz;
```

works fine, so a field name containing a colon character does not seem to cause problems for Access SQL as such.

An ODBC linked table to a SQL Server table with the same structure does not cause problems either.

In both cases the queries were run from within Access 2010 itself.

Answer (score 0):

So we might be in diagnosis mode, so lets try

```
    SELECT * FROM Task
```

and then look at the FieldNames that come back.